# Best Matched function for PHP HttpRequest Class in C#

Tags: c#, php, post, get, httpwebrequest

I am developing an App where I would need to perform HTTP Request using C#.
Had in been PHP, I could use the HttpRequest class. Which class or group of class is best matched for the PHP HttpRequest by which I could make GET and POST Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes in the System.Net namespace.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(host));
req.UserAgent = "Test";
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

req.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
  //do something with the response
}
```

Comment: As I look into the documentation, just verifying how to do Raw POST Data.

Comment: It's not needed, I just included it to show how it's done. You can't set the UserAgent header directly, and in any case, some servers might deny your request if you don't include a UserAgent. It's just an example to show you the ropes, as I remember myself having problems with it in the beginning as well (the whole RequestStream thingy etc).

Answer (score 1):

HttpWebRequest
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx